# Is there some different plugins under Sublime Text 2 for PHP Auto-Complete?

Tags: php, ide, sublimetext2, code-completion, sublime-text-plugin

I use Sublime Text 2 to write PHP. I need PHP autocomplete. But I've found out that the AutoComplete under sublime text 2 always provide inaccurate results. So I disabled that feature by adding `"auto_complete_selector": "comment"`, in the user setting. And I installed SublimeCodeIntel. But I found that the delay time of SublimeCodeIntel is so long (about 1 second or more).

I search a lot of things on google. but I really cannot find something useful to solve this problem. Finally, I found there is one plugin called PHPCodeIntel, but unfortunately, it can only be used under Sublime text 3 -- I don't want to use Sublime text 3 for some complicated reasons.

**So my questions are:**

- Is there some other plugins for php autocomplete under Sublime Text 2?
- Are there any solutions for making the SublimeCodeIntel's autocomplete pop list come out immediately?

Comment: Sublime is "just" an editor with some additional functions, I would recommend an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans for codecompletion. There are alot more features for professional development than sublime 2 or even sublime 3 can offer these days.

Comment: @P0rnflake Yes, I also use the "PHPStorm", but many my friends told me sublime text is really good. So I really hope to have a try. The PHP auto-complete of sublime text is the only thing to trouble me under sublime text. So I really hope to get the solutions. And thank you for you time and consideration :)